# Change position when scrolling until next div?

Tags: javascript, scroll

The following JavaScript seemed to work pretty well, until I discovered that the height of the div (with id="fixed") was not the same for all pages.

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    if (window.scrollY >= 450) {
      document.getElementById('fixed').style.position = 'relative';
    }
    if (window.scrollY <= 450) {
      document.getElementById('fixed').style.position = 'fixed';
    }
  });
</script>
```

For this reason I'd like to adjust it in a way that the position of the div would change as soon as it is scrolled into the the next div with id="next-to-fixed".

I saw another post that implemented jQuery for this, but I only want to use simple JavaScript, so if someone can illustrate me with a way to achieve this, that would be great.

Trial:

```
  <script>
  window.addEventListener("scroll",function() {
  var elm1 = document.getElementById('product-essential');
  if(window.scrollY >= elm1.clientHeight) {
  document.getElementById('fixed').style.position = 'relative';
  }
  if(window.scrollY <= elm1.clientHeight) {
  document.getElementById('fixed').style.position = 'fixed';
  }
  }
  );
  </script>
```

Comment: So read the height of the div and use that

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can read the `height` of a `div`:

```
var clientHeight = document.getElementById('myDiv').clientHeight;
```

and from here on use `clientHeight`.

Comment: Hi. Could you take a look at my trial code? As soon as I scroll the height of the div with Id="product-essential", the position of the div with id="fixed" should change. But why does it not change?

Comment: @Eduardo what is the value of elm1.clientHeight? Is the code entering any of the ifs (a debugger breakpoint would help in determining that)? Also, if you create a JSFiddle where the problem can be reproduced, then I might be able to give you a solution.